# Can't reference betwen Class Libary and WCF Class Libary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, reference, sharedpreferences, class-library

I'm currently trying to learn ASP.NET MVC.. But I'm strugling about to use my Interface(Class Lib) in WCF Lib... I tried to use diffrent Nuget's but none of them helped me.. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add libraries by using the using library name or by right-clicking the reference folder to select the libraries you want to reference in the frame.

Reference other projects Select the solution in the folder where you added the reference and then select another project name.

Comment: Well I'ts looks like I was using the NetCore Libary and NetCore didin't work with WCF. I re-build the my solution with Framework Libaries and that work but thanks!!!